# Remove multiplication from python's eval()

Tags: python, eval

I have a set of functions that I want to use to limit pythons eval(). The problem is, some of the reasonable inputs for this process are operators being evaluated that I don't want to.  Based on other answers I have tried removing builtins and locals but operators are still being evaluated. How can I get eval to ONLY use the functions that I provide?

```
def foo(a,b):
    return str(a) + '*' + str(b)

kwards = {'foo':foo}

eval("foo(2,2)*2", {'__builtins__':None}, kwards)
'2*22*2'
```

Desired output: '2*2*2'

Comment: Please be very aware that `{'__builtins__':None}` does not make `eval` even remotely safe. If you need safety, consider using the ast module and evaluating nodes manually.

Comment: You could split the string at "*", eval each piece, and then put it back together

Comment: I.e. `"*".join([eval(i) for i in "foo(2, 2)*2".split("*")])` or similar, though only if you don't use brackets

Comment: @Nearoo the input is not known beforehand, I also have dozens of functions so it would be impossible to build a manual solution that covers all cases